# Passing state/data to Google Apps Script ServerHandler

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to work out how I can pass some arbitrary state to a ServerHandler in Google Apps Script. The following code illustrates the question - can anybody help?

Thanks.

```
function myFunc(e) {
// want to get my data object back out here..?
}


function setUp()  
{
  var data = getMyDataArray();

  // ... set up UI...  
  var h = app.createServerHandler('myFunc');

  // How do I passs my data object to the myFunc handler?
  flow.add(app.createButton().setText("OK").addClickHandler(h));

  app.add(flow); 
  s.show(app);  
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Hidden elements](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_hidden) to store arbitrary data and send it along with a server handler invocation. The issue is that the the element can only store a string. But you can solve this using JSON.

```
function myFunc(e) {
  var yourObj = Utilities.jsonParse(e.parameter.yourObject);
  //do what you need
}


function setUp()  
{
  var data = getMyDataArray();

  // ... set up UI...  

  var hidden = app.createHidden("yourObject", Utilities.jsonStringify(data));
  var h = app.createServerHandler('myFunc').addCallbackElement(hidden);
  flow.add(app.createButton().setText("OK").addClickHandler(h));

  app.add(flow); 
  s.show(app);  
}
```